# jd-eclipse for dynamically generated java classes

Tags: java, decompiling

I was looking at [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) to be able to view contents of class files. Does anyone know if it is possible to view contents of dynamically generated classes (say proxies) loaded in the JVM using this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JD-Eclipse can read only physical class files, it won't read in-memory classes

Answer (score -1):

I think using a combination of JAD and JADClipse you should be able to do that unless class files are run through obfuscator.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how? Thanks!